# How to return value from async

Tags: python, async-await

I am running an example posted [here](https://bscscan-python.pankotsias.com/bscscan.modules.html). I modified the code a little bit and want to get data values and print outside the main function as show in the code. But I am getting an error message

```
<Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Py\untitled15.py:7>>
```

I am not good using **async** method. It must be something related to this.

I'm using spyder with Python 3.8.3. Here is the code:

```
from bscscan import BscScan
import asyncio

YOUR_API_KEY = '-------' # private keys
adr = '----------' # any address

async def main():
  async with BscScan(YOUR_API_KEY) as bsc: 
        data = await bsc.get_bep20_token_transfer_events_by_address(
                address=adr,
                startblock=0,
                endblock=999999999,
                sort="asc"
            )
        
  return data
#===========================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # asyncio.run(main()) #this does not work inside spyder
    data = asyncio.create_task(main()) #this works inside spyder
    print(data)
```

Comment: use `data = await main()`